# Loop in recursion in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming

I have stumbled upon the following problem. Say I have a recursive function like

```
run :: [Int] -> [Int]
run [] = []
run (x:xs) = 1:x:run xs
```

The important thing about it is that it `head $ run <whatever>` is always `1`. This means 
that the following will produce the output `1`:

```
head $ run [error "shouldnt get here"]
```

This proves that Haskell doesn't evaluate the argument if it doesn't need to -- obviously, since that's one of the most famous Haskell features. However, if I were to use the result as an argument, like:

```
let out = run (cycle out) in head out
```

I get a runtime error `<<loop>>`.

How come?

I am using `runghc 8.4.2`. Is that a bug or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`run (error "urk!")` will error out.

Instead, `run [error "urk!"]` will successully return `1`.

Why? Because `run` is defined by cases: empty list, nonempty list. Hence it has to evaluate its argument just enough to know if the list is empty or not. We don't have to evaluate the error in `[error "urk!"]` to see that the list is not empty, but we have if `error "urk!"` is the list itself.

In the posted code, we evaluate `run (cycle out)` so we have to check if `cycle out` is empty or not. This triggers the evaluation of `cycle out`, which in turn triggers the evaluation of `out` (`cycle` is defined by cases as well). Since `out` is what we are defining, we get an infinite recursion.

It happens that this infinite recursion is easy enough to be spotted by the GHC runtime, which kindly emits an exception `<<loop>>` instead of perform the non terminating computation.

---

To stress the concept, consider these functions

```
strictPrepend :: [Int] -> [Int]
strictPrepend []     = 1 : []
strictPrepend (x:xs) = 1 : x : xs

lazyPrepend :: [Int] -> [Int]
lazyPrepend xs = 1 : xs
```

One might think that these functions are equal. Indeed, the first one is defined by cases, but in both cases it performs the same operation (prepending `1`), so it looks equivalent to the second.

Concretely, we have that for all *bottom free* lists `ys`, the result of `strictPrepend ys` is the same as `lazyPrepend ys`.

In the presence of bottoms (like `error ".."`, `undefined`, or infinite recursion), these functions differ. For instance `lazyPrepend undefined = 1 : undefined`, while `strictPrepend undefined = undefined` since it raises an exception before producing the initial element `1`.

Consequently,

```
let ys = strictPrepend ys
    zs = lazyPrepend zs
```

defines `ys` as bottom (infinite recursion) but `zs = 1:1:1:1:.....` is an infinite sequence of `1`s. This is the effect of producing the `1` before needing to evaluate the argument.

Answer (score 4):

> The important thing about it is that it `head $ run <whatever>` is always `1`.

Actually, no. Only when `whatever` is a non-empty list. When you pass in `[]`, the `run` function will return an empty list. The argument of `run` *is* evaluated, to the point where it can decide what case to match, in [WHNF](https://wiki.haskell.org/Weak_head_normal_form). This does not evaluate the content of the list or the tail of the list.

In `let out = run (cycle out)`, the `cycle` function has exactly the same problem - it needs to pattern match the list. Since that depends on the result of `cycle` itself, you would have a recursive evaluation, which the runtime complains about.